# Post service called once but gets invoked twice on .NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, .net

I'm exposing post service on .NET Core API and I'm calling it with `HttpClient` from a WPF application. I need to pass `WindowsIdentity` with the call, found the solution, need to set `DefaultCredentials` on `HttpClientHandler`. But when I set it to true, the Web API service gets invoked twice, once with `ClaimsIdentity` and the second time with `WindowsIdentity`. I need only one call with `WindowsIdentity`.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler 
{ 
  Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials 
});

var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
var res = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: How are you calling that?

Comment: Are you sure the first request isn't an Options request ?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - the code above is the calling code, i've places break point in the rest api, and i see 2 calls only when DefaultCredentials is set, if i make a clean instance of HttpClient, the API gets invoked only once.

Comment: @Sam - not sure what you mean by options request

Comment: @Alex well, I don't know if HttpClient does this, But browsers do and HttpClient might : it is common to send a HTTP OPTIONS request prior to sending a HTTP POST in order to get some information, like CORS options. See - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS  ... perhaps double check the HTTP verb when you're debugging it next time.

Comment: @sam I dont think this is the case, i'm debugging inside POST method, so i guess it was called with POST

Answer (score 0):

Seems its normal and part of kerberos authentication